How to solve circular dependencies in C language
The system software includes two sub-modules mod_a and mod_b, which lead to circular dependencies due to the following reasons

mod_a and mod_b need to use the public definition of sys, so they need to include sys_com.h
sys_com.h provides a memory management interface. You need to know the memory node size (sizeof) of each module, so it contains mod_a.h and mod_b.h.

My personal idea is to create a new com.h, move the definitions of MOD_A_TYPE_1 and MOD_B_TYPE_1 to this file, and sys_com.h, mod_a.h and mod_b.h all include header files.
We often encounter similar problems during the project development process. What are your principles for dealing with them?Thanks in advance.
// mod_a.h

#include "sys_com.h"

typedef struct
{
    int len;
} MOD_A_TYPE_1;

// mod_b.h

#include "sys_com.h"

typedef struct
{
    int size;
} MOD_B_TYPE_1;

//sys_com.h

#include "mod_a.h"
#include "mod_b.h"

#define SYS_MOD_A_TYPE_1_SIZE           sizeof(MOD_A_TYPE_1)
#define SYS_MOD_B_TYPE_1_SIZE           sizeof(MOD_B_TYPE_1) 

// pool_type
#define SYS_MEM_POOL_MOD_A_TYPE_1       1
#define SYS_MEM_POOL_MOD_B_TYPE_1       2

// @pool_type: SYS_MEM_POOL_MOD_A_TYPE_1/SYS_MEM_POOL_MOD_B_TYPE_1
void* sys_alloc_pool_mem(int pool_type)


MOD_A_TYPE_1 and MOD_B_TYPE_1 are declared as variables above. Did you forget the typedef?

The code above does not show why you need #include "sys_com.h" in mod_a.h and mod_b.h.

The way to solve circular dependencies is to not have any in the first place. Do whatever it takes. You don't have to save every single clock cycle, you can very well call some function that will return a sizeof if that will confine all knowledge of that size in a single module.

struct {     int len; } MOD_A_TYPE_1; do not define data in header files


sys_com.h provides a memory management interface. You need to know the memory node size (sizeof) of each module, so it contains mod_a.h and mod_b.h.

Do you? Why? It seems to me that your API has a flag to choose the struct type but it does not need to use the size directly. The way I would do this is to put the #define for the sizes directly in the C file. In fact, I question the need for the #defines at all. What advantage do they give you over directly using sizeof(type)? I think sys_com.h should look like this:
// pool_type
#define SYS_MEM_POOL_MOD_A_TYPE_1       1
#define SYS_MEM_POOL_MOD_B_TYPE_1       2

// @pool_type: SYS_MEM_POOL_MOD_A_TYPE_1/SYS_MEM_POOL_MOD_B_TYPE_1
void* sys_alloc_pool_mem(int pool_type)

and sys_com.c should do the following
#include sys_com.h
#include "mod_a.h"
#include "mod_b.h"

// If you really must have the #defines
#define SYS_MOD_A_TYPE_1_SIZE           sizeof(MOD_A_TYPE_1)
#define SYS_MOD_B_TYPE_1_SIZE           sizeof(MOD_B_TYPE_1) 

void* sys_alloc_pool_mem(int pool_type)
{
// Implementation using the #defines or better sizeof(type)
}


Also consider putting include guards1 on all the headers to prevent circular includes e.g. in mod_a.h
#if !defined(_MOD_A_H)
#define _MOD_A_H

typedef struct
{
    int len;
} MOD_A_TYPE_1;

#endif


1 Many C compilers have #pragma once to do the same thing but it is not standard.

Project coding standards do not allow macros to be defined in .c files

@nnhuang Your project coding standards are wrong. If you want a macro with single file scope, it's pointless putting it in a header file. The .c file is the correct place to put it. Anyway, you can get around it by using sizeof(type) directly.

Thank you for your reply. I agree with your point of view. In order to take into account the project coding standards, I have an idea. Is it feasible? SYS_MOD_A_TYPE_1_SIZE is still defined in sys_com.h, but defined as the specific data of sizeof(MOD_A_TYPE_1), and then check whether the value of this macro is equal to sizeof(MOD_A_TYPE_1) in the mod_a.c file? Or check in the test case of mode_a. This method is not easy to maintain, because if MOD_A_TYPE_1 is modified, SYS_MOD_A_TYPE_1_SIZE must also be modified.

This can reduce the dependency of sys_com.c/sys_comh on MOD_A_TYPE_1, and there is no need to include mod_a.h. It seems to achieve decoupling, but it is @JeremyP necessary to check whether SYS_MOD_A_TYPE_1_SIZE is correct in mod_a.c. Once MOD_A_TYPE_1 is modified, SYS_MOD_A_TYPE_1_SIZE must also be modified. I really hope that sys_com.c/sys_com.h does not include the header files of the submodules. I wonder if there is a good way to achieve this.

May be your can use an other file to declare your types.
So:

sys_com.h includes mod_types.h, not mod_a.h or mod_b.h
mod_a.h and mod_b.h includes sys_com.h

Does it fit to your case ?
